# haproxy SSL Load balancer empty response

Tags: haproxy

my haproxy.cfg

```
global
    maxconn 50000

defaults
    timeout connect 10s
    timeout client 30s
    timeout server 30s
    log global
    mode http
    option httplog
    maxconn 3000

frontend bravo

bind 0.0.0.0:443 ssl crt /etc/haproxy.ssl/haproxy.pem
mode tcp
acl app1       path_beg -i /abc
acl app2            path_beg -i /xyx

use_backend     back_app1   if      app1
use_backend     back_app2   if      app2




backend back_app1
        server host1 192.168.2.32:8444/xvx
        server host2 192.168.2.33:8444/xvx  backup

backend back_app2
        server host1 192.168.2.32:8444
        server host2 192.168.2.33:8444  backup
```

When I browse for `https://haproxy/abc` or `https://haproxy/xyx` I'm getting

```
This page isn’t working
haproxy  didn’t send any data.
ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
```

Answer (score 0):

`path_beg` is not available in `mode tcp`.  See for example https://serverfault.com/questions/736694/how-to-select-different-backend-based-on-uri-when-using-mode-tcp